# How do I enable small window displaying my own camera view in Skype?

Tags: skype

I have upgraded my version of Skype to the version 6.18.64.106. Running on Win 8.1.

Ever since the upgrade I can't see my own camera view (the small window) when making a video call.
I can't figure how where to enable it.

Can anyone please advise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To turn off:

- Right-click the video, then click “ Hide Myself View“

To turn back on:

- Right-click the video, then click “ Hide Myself View“ again

Comment: Postill - Unfortunately, I don't see the option that you describe. I see the following options:

End Call
Send IM
Send SMS Message
Send Contacts...
Send files...
---------------------
View Profile
Rename...
---------------------
Block This Person...
Remove Contacts